# Load all csv files matching a regex

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to load all the files matching a given regex in a directory? I see lot of examples where the filenames are know beforehand, but what i need is to load files based on regex, something like :

```
d3.csv("data/Jan*.csv", function(data) {
    processData(data);
});
```

Would prefer to do it as much as possible on client side first. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would request the file list from the server, then return that list before processing through the `d3.csv()` as i don't think there is a function built in!

Comment: There is no way to directly get the list of files from the server from the client side.. You will need the server to return the list..

Comment: The files are bundled in a {{data}} dir along with other js. I just need to load some files matching a given regex.

Comment: Im afraid you still hit the problem where the JS client side has no access to the said `{{data}} dir` ... In order to run a regex it needs to be aware of the contents of the folder, which it doesnt have any idea about.

Comment: @Pogrindis, then how come `"data/Jan01.csv"` works? Even without any server side code.

Comment: because you have told the client side javascript "The file `Jan01.csv` is there, go and get it." You could put in a file that doesnt exist and then you get 404 not found.. **The client slide JS knows nothing about the server other than what you tell it**